# How do I fix these faces? Weird shapes

Tags: edges, faces, topology

I'm having a problem with the faces in the corners of this pillow where they keep reverting back to a weird jagged shape that's very noticeable at certain angles.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried adding an edge in the middle which worked but then I have triangles which I would rather avoid. I also tried dissolving the edges but the faces did not keep that shape and just went back to how they were. I also tried removing the faces and manually filling them again which worked but only once like here:

[image]

I'm not really sure what else to try, any ideas? :(
Thanks

Comment: Try to add subdivide modifier? The quad you show is severely bent. Remember that a quad should represent a flat plane instead a bent surface, the mesh edge flow should follow the shape of your model

Comment: I would probably bake the normal map in high resolution to kindly remind the shader how was  surface look like

Answer (score 0):

Click the faces which have that problem and subdivide those.
Or

Use a subdivision surface modifier(would increase the poly count